# How to authorize with amazon cloud drive and get the photos of the user from cloud drive?

Tags: android, cloud, drive, amazon-clouddrive

I want to authorize user and then want to access user photo that are available on a cloud drive. Kindly guide me how to access user cloud drive in android application and get user photos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you check out [Amazon Cloud Drive API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive)? You would use [Login with Amazon](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/engage/login-with-amazon) for authorization, and then use the Cloud Drive's [Nodes API](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes) to retrieve a list of photos.

> Getting List of files.
>
> GET : {{metadataUrl}}/drive/v1/nodes?filters=kind:FILE
>
> filters: (Optional) filters for request, see [filtering](https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/nodes#Filtering)

Comment: i m using the url to authenticate the user url is as follow

https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa?client_id=amzn1.application-oa2-client.5b7abaada12f46218b2d9f8506cb50d9&scope=clouddrive%3Aread%20clouddrive%3Awrite &response_type=token&redirect_uri=http://nextin.co

it is giving error in the redirect uri error is as follow

http://nextin.co/?error=invalid_scope&error_description=An+unknown+scope+was+requested

Comment: @rana_sadam Did you [whitelist](https://developer.amazon.com/cd/sp/overview.html) your security profile? [see here](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=4619&tstart=15)